# Setting background in a game without using Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I'm making a simple game, like [this one](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4dyKnQorlPh4lFERv6bIHPZ05_2e0qGQ4gO-Lb8wHVdx_z0u3XqosrY5sbhIhKF7Hymh=h900), where you have to go through that little space between the 2 lines, but all my lines are descending and you can only move your character left/right at the bottom of the screen.

I've been wandering through a lot of topics (most from -2014) and found out that the best way to draw a background on a cansa is by using a bitmap. The problem is that this takes a lot of resources, my FPS dropping from 40+ to <20.

This is what I found :

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.big_background),0,0,null);
```

Is there any better way? Like setting the `setContentView` to a specific XML activity, knowing that in order for my lines to descend, I need to redraw them 30 times/ sec ?

Comment: I would decode the resource 1 time and save it for reuse

Comment: Could you expand your explanation ? The truth being I've never done something like this before, I do not understand what has to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David has it right: save the Bitmap once and reuse it when you need to draw.

1. In your Activity, add `private Bitmap bg;`
2. In the `onCreate()`, add `bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.big_background);`
3. You can now do `canvas.drawBitmap(bg);` without incurring the bitmap load penalty.